# application crashed with NumberFormatException

Tags: android, runtimeexception, numberformatexception

Code

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText a;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a);

        int i = Integer.parseInt(a.getText().toString());
  }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.shoaib.demo/com.example.shoaib.demo.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
>                         at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>                         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101)
>                         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>                         at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:629)
>                         at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
>                         at com.example.shoaib.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7117)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7108)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)

Comment: Check if a is null or not. Your application crashed probably because you got a null pointer exception in accessing a. It is probably null. Can you paste the backing xml for this activity?

Comment: String null cannot be converted into int. The edit text might contain a null value so check it .

Comment: It would be nice to know what troubleshooting steps you tried first, or what was happening when the application crashed.  You'll get more responses that way than just throwing us a log dump. :)

Comment: You can't convert an empty `String` to `int`. Furthermore why do you set `android:inputType="textPersonName"` when you obviously need an `int`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because the `EditText` is not created on the UI yet.

But, you need the *EditText on the screen, along with some valid data* before you can call `Integer.parseInt`.

You need to use some sort of interface, through which you would call `Integer.parseInt`. I suggest using a button.

If you don't want to add a button though, use this code:

```
a.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(a.getText().toString());
        //any operation involving i
        return true;
    }
});
```

Then, after you type some data into `a`, long press `a`, and see the magic!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to convert a non int (" " - since the edittext is probably empty) character into an int character.
You can try this code below;

```
String input = a.getText().toString();

if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(input)) {
     i = Integer.parseInt(input);
     // do everything you want with your int here
}
```